# How to rotate only the camera in ThreeJS dragging the mouse in the scene?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, camera, virtual-reality

I'm working in a ThreeJS project and I want to rotate the camera with the mouse. I've seen that with *OrbitControls*,  I can rotate my camera around a point or an object but I cant rotate my camera like a First Person Shooter Videogame. *TrackballsControls* have the same problem that orbit controls, I can rotate and move my camera around a specific point in my 3d space but I cant rotate the camera itself..

*PointerLockControls* could be a solution but it rotates the camera while I move the mouse for my scene, and I want to click and drag to rotate the camera.

I want to copy the camera of this project: http://showroom.littleworkshop.fr/ in which I think they works with OrbitControls, enable and disable this propertive of the camera.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try [FirstPersonControls.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/FirstPersonControls.js)?

Comment: Thank's @TheJim01 I'm using PointerLockControls.js which is the "next" advanced version of FirstPersonControls. I read it in others websites.

Comment: @fjavier10 Check out how the "video" and "cube" examples are implemented [here](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=panorama).

Comment: @WestLangley This is good only when we have statis position for camera!

Comment: Did you find solution in the end? Because i have the same problem.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

*(**I appended my renderer inside a div called interactiveViewPort (interactiveViewPort.appendChild) I created, instead of the default document.body.appendChild**)*
Make a **variable** to store mouseup or mousedown state

```
let mouseDown = false;
```

Add a **mousedown event listener** on the element containing the renderer;
This event listener also starts our camera movements;

```
interactiveViewPort.addEventListener('mousedown',()=>{
    mouseDown = true
    controls.lock();

})
```

Add a **mouseup event listener** on the document; To dectect if the mouse button is no longer being pressed

```
    document.addEventListener('mouseup',()=>{
    if(mouseDown){
        mouseDown = false
        controls.unlock()
    }
})
```

So the camera movements will be stopped when the code detects a mouse up on the whole documents

Answer (score -1):

You can enable/disable PointerLockControls with the `enabled` property:

```
controls = new PointerLockControls( camera );

controls.enabled = true; // Turns on camera rotating with mouse
controls.enabled = false; // Turns it off
```

Comment: I'm trying with PointerLockControls and it works perfect but I don't want to rotate the camera when I move my mouse over the scene. I want to _"click"_ in my scene and then _"drag"_ the mouse in left or right direction, rotating the camera in the other way. Thank's for the help, I will keep working on it trying other things.